# Eigen matrices of boost rationals failing only in dimension 4

Tags: c++, boost, eigen

I'm trying to evaluate the determinants of certain small matrices exactly by using rational numbers with big integers for the numerator and denominator.
The boost multiprecision package provides a data type for this and Eigen will do linear algebra with custom scalar types.
Everything seems to work, *except* for 4D matrices!
Here's a minimal example:

```cpp
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

using Rational = boost::multiprecision::cpp_rational;

template <size_t N>
Rational rational_test() {
    Eigen::Matrix<Rational, N, N> A;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < N; ++j)
            A(i, j) = Rational(1, 1 + i + j);
    return A.determinant();
}


int main() {
    std::cout << rational_test<2>() << "\n"
              << rational_test<3>() << "\n"
              // << rational_test<4>() << "\n"
              << rational_test<5>() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Un-commenting the line for the 4D test case triggers the compile error.
If I change it to instead do

```
    return A.partialPivLu().determinant();
```

then the error goes away.
With some benchmarking in dimension 3, I get a performance hit of 4x, so while forcing it to use LU is an ok workaround for now, it's probably sacrificing performance.

I can copy the entire error message if need be but here's what I think is the operative part:

```
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/GenericPacketMath.h:956:1: note:   template 
argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/LU/Determinant.h:96:56: note:   deduced conflicti
ng types for parameter ‘const Packet’ (‘boost::multiprecision::detail::expressi
on<boost::multiprecision::detail::negate, boost::multiprecision::number<boost::
multiprecision::backends::rational_adaptor<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp
_int_backend<> > >, void, void, void>’ and ‘Eigen::internal::determinant_impl<E
igen::Matrix<boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::backends::rat
ional_adaptor<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<> > >, 4, 4, 0, 
4, 4>, 4>::Scalar’ {aka ‘boost::multiprecision::number<boost::multiprecision::b
ackends::rational_adaptor<boost::multiprecision::backends::cpp_int_backend<> > 
>’})
   96 |     return internal::pmadd(m(i0,2), d0, internal::pmadd(-m(i1,2), d1, m
(i2,2)*d2));
      |                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm wondering if there's some missing logic about how to static cast Rationals to other types, but I haven't got a clue what it needs to be.
The error doesn't go away when I add some shims recommended in the [Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_CustomScalar.html) for custom scalar types.
There's an example [here](https://gitlab.liris.cnrs.fr/vnivolie/predicats/blob/3425064ebe231d03c6e1fa1ac01b7fa5d00a9674/Code/precision.cpp#L19) of making Eigen work with Boost intervals that includes some template specializations of `is_convertible` that looks possibly relevant.